# How do I get the list of all the cameras?

Tags: vb.net, camera

I have this code right now:

```
Public Touchless As New TouchlessLib.TouchlessMgr
Public Camera1 As TouchlessLib.Camera = Touchless.Cameras.ElementAt(0)
```

But it gets just one camera. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `Touchless.Cameras` is a list of cameras and by doing `Cameras.ElementAt(0)` you are explicitly selecting the first from the list.

try this:

```
Public cameras() As TouchlessLib.Camera = Touchless.Cameras
```

Then you can use `cameras(0)` to access the first camera, `cameras(1)` the second, and so on.

Or you can just loop Cameras like this:

```
For Each cam As TouchlessLib.Camera In Touchless.Cameras
    ' do what you want with cam
next
```